# python error - invalid argument: can't kill an exited process

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, gecko

```
import sys
link = sys.argv[1]
link = link.replace("%26", "&")
link = link.replace("######", "&amp;")
myProxy = sys.argv[2]

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

proxy = Proxy({
  'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': ''
})

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.Proxy = proxy
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10000)
driver.get(link)
s = driver.page_source
print((s.encode("utf-8")))
print (driver.get_cookies())
driver.quit()
```

This code works perfect few days ago and then i just noticed this message:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

I searched for some solutions on the internet, and people suggest to put this in the code:

```
 options = Options()
    options.headless = True
```

But I already have this in my code so that still is not the solution to my problem, is there anything else that I can do? Any help or suggestion in which way I should go to find the solution for this will be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Based on proxy settings i think the problem is in noProxy option

webdriver W3C says it should be an **array**

Reference: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#proxy

Review the options and values your provide for missconfiguration.